# Map port of Elasticsearch in Docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, networking, port

I want to start an Elasticsearch container in Docker. By default I see nearly everywhere something like:

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

Now is my question: Why are we mapping the port on our host network? I understand port mapping but I don't see the big advantage of it.

In my opinion I would always do something like this:

```
$ docker network create logging
20aa4c7bf2d8289d8cbd485c3e384f9371eed87204625998687c61e4bad27f14

$ docker run -d --name es --net logging docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

And connect to the ES by using it's name (es in this case) and deploying containers in the same network. I would think my ES is more secure in its private docker network.

I see there is an advantage for port mapping when your containers which need to connect to elasticsearch aren't in the same network. But are there other advantages or why is this always shown with port mapping?

Answer (score 0):

So host access is more about accessibility. If you are running docker on local machine and you want to access the app only on that machine, then host mapping is not need.

Now if you need to access this app on a external computer other than your docker host then you need to do that port mapping.

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

This maps the host port 9200 (left side) to 9200 inside the docker (right side). The listening interface is `0.0.0.0` which means all interfaces. And hence it is accessible to to anyone how has access to this machine.

If you want to make it more secure then you do it like below

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

This would listen on local host only. So only you can access it on the machine. But if you need to access it from some place else then you would use a SSH tunnel

```
ssh -L 9200:127.0.0.1:9200 <user>@<HOSTIP>
```

And on that machine you can access it on 127.0.0.1:9200

Next level of security is added when you use a firewall like `ufw`, `firewalld` etc.

What you did with network command

```
docker network create logging
```

Basically creates new network and isolates other docker containers from accessing it on the host. But as long as external accessibility is concerned, you still need to map it to the host port

Hope this answers your question